# Generalized Threading Macro in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

Note: this is NOT about concurrency. This is about the thread macro.

I know that `->` puts the object at the 2nd position and `->>` puts the argument at the last position.

Now, I'm curious, much like the short hand notation of `#( ... % )` for functions, is there a short hand notation for threads that lets me place the argument at *arbitrary* location?

The goal would be that instead of having a fixed location for the thread to run through ... I can write arbitrary forms, and insert %% at special places, and the %% is where the thread gets inserted.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the question. I've been wanting to ask that for ages. Sometimes I have to use (#(func-adaptor arg1 % arg2)) to get the effect I want with -> or ->>.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The 'diamond wand' from [Swiss Arrows](https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows) library would do what you're asking for:

```
(-<> 0
 (* <> 5)
 (vector 1 2 <> 3 4))
; => [1 2 0 3 4]
```

That said, it isn't something you end up needing often (or *ever* in my Clojure experience)

Comment: I like how these macros abuse the flexibility of clojure variable names

Comment: Better yet, as of version 1.5, Clojure provides `as->` as explained in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17635433/109618).

Comment: I use `as->` fairly often, but I like the succinctness and visual clarity of the diamond wand.  Usually happens when common functions with differing arity, such as `map` and `assoc`, are used within the same thread.

Answer (score 37):

There is now a generalized threading macro in Clojure since 1.5 called [as->](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c9e70649d2652baf13b498c4c3ebb070118c4573/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6913).

This tweet gives an example of how it works: https://twitter.com/borkdude/status/302881431649128448

```
(as-> "/tmp" x
      (java.io.File. x)
      (file-seq x)
      (filter (memfn isDirectory) x)
      (count x))
```

First 'x' is bound to "/tmp" and a file is made out of it. 'x' is rebound again to the resulting file and a put through the 'file-seq' function, etc.

Comment: The Swiss Arrows library is fun and all, but this is probably the best answer as of 2014, since it is built into Clojure since version 1.5.

Comment: Github code examples here: https://github.com/search?q=as-%3E+extension%3A.clj&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else comes across this, there is a reason the provided macros exist, but an arbitrary placement one does not: the latter would lead to poor API design.

The `->` macro places the argument in the first position.  This corresponds to functions that work on some subject argument, e.g., `conj`, `assoc`.

The `->>` macro places the argument in the last position.  This corresponds to functions that work on sequences, e.g., `map`, `reduce`.

Design your APIs well, and you'll be less likely to need such a macro.

Comment: Well-reasoned, Alex. Though sometimes you need to thread data through functions that you didn't design. I guess one can always use a (#(f a1 % a3)) to get around it.

Comment: `nth` is a good example of a core function that works on a collection but expects it not as the last arg but as the first.

Comment: `nth` also doesn't return a sequence like the others,  making it work well when digging into a nested sequences.  I think that's why it's structured that way.

Answer (score 2):

There was a library that provided this feature, but I forgot where. It might of been in the deprecated clojure-contrib. It was the `-$>` macro.

But you could derive one from clojure's core [-> macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1529) to make the one you're looking for:

```
(defmacro -$>
    ([x] x)
    ([x form] (if (seq? form)
                (with-meta (map #(if (= %1 '$) x %1) form) (meta form))
                (list form x)))
    ([x form & more] `(-$> (-$> ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

And use $ to indicate the insertion point:

```
user=> (-$> 2 str (identity $) (println $))
2
nil
```

Technically, you could use multiple `$` in one form. But this implementation suffers from expanding the same form multiple times (in exchange for simplicity).